# Where did the standard arcade font originate?

Tags: history, arcade, font

[image: Classic arcade font]

Nearly anyone who has seen an early arcade game from any company has probably seen this or a very similar font. Who created it and where, and why did it become so widespread, ending up in games from completely different companies?

Comment: There aren't that many ways you can draw an 8x8 font with lines that are at least two pixels wide so they show up on the display. So they're going to tend to look similar.

Comment: Japanese developers created it but there were several variations. They all copied each other and I don't think there was an original as such.

Comment: I don't know whether it is still true, but US law is (was?) unusual in the way it treats font IP.  You could trademark a font's name, but could not protect the patterns of dots which make up the font characters.  So even if multiple vendors were using the same font shapes, it would have been legal in the USA.

Comment: I was just about to ask a similar question and found this as a duplicate.  Look at this: https://www.gamesdatabase.org/game/arcade/sprint-2 - that's a 1976 black-and-white Atari arcade game where that font appears (except the E is slightly different).  That might be the earliest example.  I think the font had to have originated with Atari (way back when it was Kee Games).

Comment: @LawrenceC Good find! The programmers were Dennis Koble and Lyle Rains. I think they're both on LinkedIn if someone wants to ask them where they got the font from or whether they designed it themselves. Earlier arcade games didn't have much text other than a numerical score, and I also don't think it's a terminal font because it doesn't seem to be designed for readability. Maybe you could expand your comment into an answer.

Comment: I came here somehow thinking that this would be about the ["Mantronix font"](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://community.soulstrut.com/discussion/14975/real-designers-what-is-the-mantronix-font), so I'm commenting just in case anyone else makes the same mistake I did. :)

Comment: You can see the Atari Centipede font [here](https://6502disassembly.com/va-centipede/graphics.html). For me, the thing that distinguishes the Atari font is the stylish '8' digit. Missile Command has nearly the same font, but you'll notice the Centipede/Sprint2 glyph for 'E' uses different lengths for all 3 horizontals, and MC doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It's a bold 8x8 pixel sans font.**

Hard- and software wise using an 8x8 font is the most simple way to go and to create emphasis making it bold needs the least effort. Within an 8x8 grid, there aren't many ways to create fonts and even fewer bold ones (*1).

When bolding, the font design choice in 8x8 is usually vertical doubling, due the rather upright nature of latin characters. Vertical offers more room while still keeping a recognizable ratio. There is as well not much room for bells and whistles, as the main concern is still readability - after all, it's all geared to make the reader play, not decipher text.

Bottom line: **Similarity evolved as a result of restricted resources and desired function.**

Which BTW is true for any classic 'font' design - next to all scripts design can in large parts be attributed to the technology used for creation. It wasn't until the movable letter and highres displays that it got freed from such mundane limitations :)

---

The font issue nothing specific to arcade games, but true for all microcomputers using low resolution displays, with 8x8 being a cornerstone. IBM's CGA gives a great example, as its charset was as well 8x8 and by default available in bold (lower half):

[image: IBM PC CGA Font]
(picture taken and upscaled from https://www.seasip.info/VintagePC/cga.html )

Now, using an 8x8 grid doesn't mean there is not room for variations, above CGA font designers even managed to include basic elements of a serifed font integrated - visible on some of the upper case letters - while the font mentioned in the question and many other 8x8 fonts go for a more simple sans style.

[This nice page](https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/) ([supplied](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13173/where-did-the-standard-arcade-font-originate#comment41756_13176) by LangLangC) shows a wide variety of character sets used on PC and PC like systems. There are many font variations within 8x8. People invested a lot of time to customise appearance. But when it comes to simple, conventional, easy to read fonts, the limited resources in pixels and shapes make them superficially the same.

---

*1 - As Ross Ridge already [commented](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13173/where-did-the-standard-arcade-font-originate#comment41744_13173)

Comment: Here are just two other bold 8x8 fonts: https://style64.org/file/image/projects/c64_truetype.png and https://www.ffonts.net/ZX-Spectrum-7-Bold.font (the latter is made programmatically from the non-bold default ZX Spectrum ROM font), and it is obvious they are all different. So "Within an 8x8 grid, there aren't many ways to create fonts" is simply not true. You can find unlimited kinds of fonts in various demoscene productions on 8bit machines.

Comment: @lvd your point is? Of course there is variation. The CGA font for example is even a serifed one - whereas the above and the ones you cite are sans. But that's not the point here. Mind you, the question explicite mentiones _"this or a very similar font"_ And I thing we can agree that the ones you cite are _very similar_ aren't they?

Comment: What is the measure of 'similarity'? For the pixel artists, they all are different.

Comment: @lvd Sure? I would think that especially a proficient pixel artist is able to take a step back and see it at whole, isn't he? And that's what similarity means - finding what things have in common, not what distinguishes them. Of course a vaild outcome may be 'nothing' and the OP is totally wrong here. Just me impression is that there is a quite high degree of similarity for an uneducated eye. Heck, modern 'pixel art' has by now left the realm of real pixels and is replicating the core traits in high resolution - don't they?

Comment: Indeed, almost [all look quite similar](https://int10h.org/oldschool-pc-fonts/fontlist/), but in reality, the used screenshot here is not very illustrative. Please use a larger view so that one can see any possible differences, which do exist.

Comment: @LаngLаngС well, it's one on one, showing quite well how puny resolutions were back then,doesn't it?

Comment: @LаngLаngС - Well, as Raffzahn says, its already 1 to 1, so a larger view would provide no additional information. If its hard to see the individual pixels, then all you have to do is zoom in on the existing image.

Comment: Would you really call that _sans-serif_?  Look at the E, I, L, P, T for starters - all are clearly serifed, in normal and bold.

Comment: It should probably be added that the question states explicitly "nearly the same" (validating this answer), that there are games (VCS eg but also others) that [do not use 'so similar' ones](http://arcade.photonstorm.com/) and that the Q itself uses apparently [*this* version](https://www.1001fonts.com/arcadeclassic-font.html). Looking through screenshots of games it looks pretty much like mainly the standard Nintendo (maybe 'Japanese'?) font (C64 eg showing much more, if tiny, variation)?

Comment: @TobySpeight Erm. The E clearly is without, and there is no  I, L, P or T :)) I guess you mixed up the answer regarding the font shown in the question (which is a sans type),  above the divider, with the IBM CGA shown as _a_ example for 8x8 fonts, below the divider. It's a stunning ability to include some serifs is noted in the paragraph below.

Comment: Ah, so the repertoire shown isn't intended to be the same arcade font?  I misunderstood that.  Reading again more carefully, I now see that's an aside about other fonts with similar constraints.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TobySpeight I added it to show that even fonts that did a good job to add style within 8x8 do still reassemble each other at first look. That's the point I tried to make. There isn't a single _'The Arcade Font'_ but many that due the shared restrictions and criteria  that make them all similar at first sight - and in memory.

Comment: FWIW, I rendered Apple's DOS Toolkit font collection on https://6502disassembly.com/a2-dtk-fonts/allfonts.bin.html . Of the 28 fonts, 14 are standard ASCII, and offer distinct looks (the rest are non-ASCII, graphics, or upside-down/mirror). They use 7x8 character cells.

Comment: @fadden: I hadn't seen that collection of fonts.  Apple seems to have missed a trick, though: when drawing characters aligned on 7-pixel boundaries, it's possible to shift any combination of rows by half a pixel, a fact which can help with characters like "v", and would really help the slanted fonts.  I recall having seen that trick used in a piece of educational software around 1987.

Comment: @supercat it's possible the fonts were meant to be shared with the Apple ///, which used the high bit as an inverse flag (see e.g. [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.apple2.programmer/romEO0g3EZk/VzbqxiyNCAAJ)). Further, the DTK [HRCG](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-starship-cmdr/H.html#SymDoOutput) could render with ORA, EOR, or AND, so it's possible they wanted to avoid color shifts when drawing text on colored backgrounds. It's also possible it just didn't occur to them (I hadn't thought of it). :-) Some high bits *are* set, but not in a useful way... so who knows.

Comment: @fadden: The intended flashing behavior seems curious.  A missed opportunity I think on the Apple II circuit design would have been to feed the two upper bits of each character code into the select inputs of a 4x2 mux, whose outputs would then be mixed together with a couple of resistors (use this in lieu of the other inverse/flash logic).  That would have accommodated normal/dim/reverse/flash quite easily, with the reverse and flash looking rather less annoying than using the existing design.  Alternatively, adding a 1Kx4 SRAM for attributes on the //e would have...

Comment: ...made it easy to support full upper and lowercase with a rich set of attributes like those of the VT100.

Answer (score 3):

In the Sprint 2 hardware design, the text is part of a character-cell based playfield, generated through a lookup into a 512x8b character ROM (actually a pair of 512x4b ROMs wired in parallel, in sockets P4 and R4).  This ROM could not be read by the CPU, but fed directly into a shift register which, after being combined with the car sprites, drove the video output.  It provided 64 characters, which were used for both the text and the background graphics.

These playfield-generator ROMs appear to have been standard mask-ROM or PROM parts, so their contents would have been specified by the game's manufacturer.  I think for earlier examples you should look for games by the same manufacturer.  Notably, this cabinet was one of the early applications of the MOS 6502, but it's plausible that an earlier game used the same font but a different CPU.

Dedicated character-generator chips also existed at the time, most notably those made by Signetics - however, these did not use the 8x8 pixel format seen here.  The contemporary DEC VT52 terminal did use a 7x7 format (which with spacing was effectively 8x8), but used a thin-line font with a very different appearance.

Comment: Might be good to specifically mention that Sprint 2 is the earliest example of such a font.

Comment: @supercat Except that I wasn't able to eliminate all possibilities myself.  After all, the game being called Sprint 2 implies that there's a Sprint 1, and that was far from the only arcade game being made at the time.

Comment: Fair point, but you should still say that you are mentioning it because it's the earliest example you know.  If memory serves, the other games I can think of didn't show any text, and used 7-segment-style digits for score readouts.  The game Night Driver had alphanumeric readout, but its font was different and I think it came later.